# Problems with pppoeconf on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, ppp

I have a problem with pppoeconf. Today, I had to reinstall Raspbian on the sdcard and after that I installed pppoe ( I followed the specification that can be found [HERE](http://daksaitay.blogspot.ro/2014/06/how-to-setup-dsl-connection-internet.html)).
Now, the problem is that everytime I run sudo pppoeconf I have an error message:

```
          | Sorry, I scanned 1 interface, but the Access             │
          │ Concentrator of your provider did not respond. Please    │
          │ check your network and modem cables. Another reason for  │
          │ the scan failure may also be another running pppoe       │
          │ process which controls the modem.
```

and all the setting seems to be OK. I have to mention that I didn't have this problem with network on the old Raspbian and also, if I plug the network cable to my computer, I can connect to internet. So the problem is only on Raspberry.

Also, the output of ifconfig -a is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:3b:9c:a2  
          inet addr:192.168.33.202  Bcast:192.168.33.255  Mask:255.255.255.192
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8240 (8.0 KiB)  TX bytes:3794 (3.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Btw, is about software that runs on Raspberry Pi and about Raspbian! In fact, this problem can be an issue to the OS or the software that was package as armhf and can run on Raspberry Pi

Comment: You solved this, and it seems like an "unreproducible issue" in light of that.

Comment: no, I didn't solve it! For example if I run sudo pppoeconf eth0, will ask me for the username and password, but in reality, it doesn't configure and connect to internet.
OK, I agree with you that looks like an "unreproducible issue" but then what can be the solution? reinstall the OS? As I said, is strange for me everything worked fine until I had to reinstall the OS.

Comment: Okay.  I'm going to reopen it and migrate it to U&L, because you're really unlikely to find any help with this here.   That's not a promise that you'll find it there, but it is a much better chance.

Comment: I understand. I really forgot about U&L and I rapidly posted on raspberry.

Comment: Seems to be a bug>>https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pppoeconf/+bug/233893